Remove "Anonymous" text from From header - SIP invite
I need to remove "Anonymous" text from below From header in INVITE request. Done following configuration but no luck.
Used Asterisk 18.23.1 built by root @ pilrh-noc-dynamicconivr-app01 on a x86_64 running Linux on 2024-06-04 09:47:24 UTC
  SIP/2.0 100 Trying
  Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 
  localip:5060;
  received=localip;branch=z9hG4bK30fa5b7b;rport=5060

   From: "Anonymous" <sip:0117411111@sipserverip>;tag=as032a1a5d
  To: <sip:07611111111@sipserverip>
  Call-ID: 3e6730894cf25b8a05ce3e40289d05bd@localip:5060
  CSeq: 102 INVITE
  Content-Length: 0    

sip.conf
[mytrunk]
type=peer
host=myhostip
port=5060
context=mycontext
disallow=all
allow=ulaw,alaw
fromuser=0117411111
fromdomain=localip
defaultuser=0117411111  ; Sometimes needed to ensure the user is sent correctly
callerid="<0117411111>
qualify=yes

extentions.conf
[from-dialog]
exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=)  ; Clear any name set for caller ID
exten => _X.,n,Set(CALLERID(num)=0117411111)  ; Set only the caller ID number
exten => _X.,n,Dial(SIP/dialog_axa/${EXTEN})
exten => _X.,n,Hangup()


Set(CALLERID(all)=0117411111)

Try this
   [from-dialog]
    exten => _X.,1,Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)})


Thank you for the reply, but still not working

Should work. Works everywhere. Maybe you not reloaded dialplan. You can also check debug output and sip traces.

Finally we modified chain_sip.c and sip.h files to achieve this.

Common, it works in every single pbx without mods
